# Not able to click on a button with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to click on a button using Protractor doesn't seem to work :

Here is what i have tried :

```js
const city = element.all(by.css('.filter-bar .filter-button-wrapper .filter-button')).get(0).click();
```

Here is the html :

```html
    <div class="content-wrapper list-page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="section-wrapper page-full-width">
                <div class="section page-centered">
                    <div class="filter-bar"><span class="medium-utility-label filter-by-label">Filter by:</span>
                        <div role="button" class="filter-button-wrapper" tabindex="0" aria-label="Filter by City: All" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div class="filter-button">City
                                <svg class="filter-button-caret icon icon-caret-down" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M7.6741598,11.3413318 L8.03952616,11.7324251 L8.40489252,11.3413318 L14.8653664,4.42595055 L14.1346336,3.74328687 L7.6741598,10.6586682 L8.40489252,10.6586682 L1.86536636,3.65866816 L1.13463364,4.34133184 L7.6741598,11.3413318 Z M7.6741598,11.3413318" fill="#979797"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div class="filter-popup">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="category-link selected" href="?" rel="nofollow">
                                            <svg class="selected-filter-checkmark icon icon-checkmark" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                <path d="M6.2,14.4L0,8.2l2.5-2.5l3.5,3.5c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0L13.5,2L16,4.5L6.2,14.4z"></path>
                                            </svg>All</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="category-link" href="?location=Chicago%2C%20Illinois" rel="nofollow">Chicago, Illinois</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="category-link" href="?location=Edmonton%2C%20Alberta%2C%20Canada" rel="nofollow">Edmonton, Alberta, Canada</a>
                                    </li>
```

Click on a button should open the drop down list.

Comment: do you have any javascript function for onclick of "filter-button" ?

Comment: No just the protractor API's to click on it.

Comment: could you please provide a working snippet of your html part

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have added the html to the description. In my test case that i'm creating using protractor this is how i'm trying to click on the button : const city = element.all(by.css('.filter-bar .filter-button-wrapper .filter-button')).get(0).click();     and nothing is happening

Comment: created a snippet from your html code just click on button manually nothing will happen the same thing will happen during the protractor also it was expected.

Comment: Understood. I just update the html. After clicking on the button it opens a drop down pop up. That's how the actual web site is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to click on the element with three classes when there is no such element and why you are using element.all when there is only one button... But I can assume you need the last div element (right before the icon).
Please try this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText(".filter-button", "City")
```